# Copy data from multiple sheets & files into one target sheet

Tags: excel, vba, file, copy

I am very NEW about programming.
I have been searching google for a week, but couldn't make the right code.
Could you help?

This is what I want to make:

1. There is One Target excel file and 22 of source excel files.
2. In the 22 of source files, there are 5 sheets(P1~P5) which contains the same structure but different data.
3. I want to copy data of K1:L1 and B13:L13 from those 5 sheets and paste to
4. the target file, at N2:Z2 on '3rdParty' sheet. Next data will be pasted on the next line.
5. Loop above 3 and 4 (paste to the next line of the last line) for the rest of the source files.
6. Close source files
   [image]

My questions are,

- How to load 22 source data from those many files?
  Now I just realized that Array' does not allow to indicate more than 12 files. Is there any good idea?
- Even though I executed with a few source files through 'Array', I could not get any results.
  VBA was moving, but nothing different on the target sheet. What is the problem?

[Explanation with Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1S4XiLdWkp2G2mgdjxaa7R_8jS9b27W/view?usp=sharing)

[Target File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jC6OhKimYwfEje-Yjdpxk6tRXwZ5T90o/view?usp=sharing)

[Source File1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J0z9pwISjuR5-uZW-fGrXusXVMtrany4/view?usp=sharing)

[Source File2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FYD8l4SJxPWehYyT7hLSA8_8zp8RV4Ch/view?usp=sharing)

### For your information, I have not coded this all by myself. I have consulted many codes on the web and combined it, so maybe there are unnecessary or improper codes.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
Sub Collect_3rd_Party_Data()
Dim SourceArray, SheetNames
Dim SourceRange1 As String
Dim SourceRange2 As String
Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook, sourceFile As Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet, SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long, lastSourceRow As Long

SourceArray = Array("C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P1.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P2.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P3.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P4.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P5.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P6.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P7.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P8.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P9.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P10.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P11.xlsm", "C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P12.xlsm",

SheetNames = Array("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5")
SourceRange1 = "K1:L1"
SourceRange2 = "B13: L13"
    
Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tefun\Desktop\Projects\Evaluation\Radar_Chart_Index.xlsm")
Set TargetSheet = TargetWorkbook.Sheets("3rdParty")

For i = 0 To UBound(SourceArray)
    Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceArray(i))
    LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row      
    Set SourceSheet = sourceFile.Sheets(SheetNames(i))  
    With SourceSheet
       lastSourceRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       .Range(SourceRange1 & lastSourceRow).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Range("N" & LastRow + 1)
       .Range(SourceRange2 & lastSourceRow).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Range("P" & LastRow + 1)
          
    End With
    sourceFile.Close            
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am using Excel2016 and OS is windows10.

Comment: Please to not include external links to macro enabled files as those can be dangerous. Instead, include the relevant part of the code, which it seems you have already done.

Comment: Where do you determine lastSourceRow ? It will be initialized as 0. Your first array is also not properly closed.

Comment: @braX Thank you for your comment. I apologize for the google drive link. I will correct it but need to know how to upload the file here first..haha. Anyway please wait for a moment.

Comment: @QHarr Sorry, i didn't put one line of that. It should have put 'lastSourceRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row' under the 'With SouceSheet'

Comment: @QHarr I have added on the code above. Thank you.

Comment: Your last row will added in a string fashion rather than numeric. Was that your intention? For example, "K1:L1" & 1 -> "K1:L11". As opposed to "K1:L" & 1 (where 1 is example lastSourceRow )

Comment: You also need a double loop if you intend to access all sheets in SheetNames. Your current code assumes same length 1d arrays and will copy a different sheet from each.

Comment: @QHarr No, I have just copied from other original code, so I didn't code it intentionally. Since I am a very beginner, I am still understudying.

Comment: @QHarr So my code doesn't collect all the source cells beyond 5(P1~P5) sheets. To solve it, I need to use the double loop. One is for copy and paste, one another is moving 5 sheets?

Comment: One is to loop all workbooks in first array; the other is to access all sheets in sheets array from a given workbook. The outer is over workbooks; the inner, over target worksheets. In the inside loop you determine next row to paste to and source row to copy from. If I have understood you - still waking up here.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you very much for your clear advice. :)

Comment: What would you recommend me to set the 22 source files?

Comment: If your source 22 workbooks file name has a specific text which always the same (it seems the text "3rd_Party_Evaluation" is always there in all the source file name), then maybe you can "loop" it via `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` which will look all the file name which has text "3rd_Party_Evaluation".

Comment: @karma Yes, file names will be '3rd_Party_Evaluation_sheet _P#' 'Thank you very much. I will try it. :)